# Greek letter wrong encoding

Tags: php

I want to display a greek phrase, namely I want to display each letter down the other and in the case that the are two words I want this output

```
Κ Η
Α Ρ
Λ Θ
Ω Ε
Σ Σ
```

I use this code:

```
<?php
$str = "HELLO HOW YA DOING WORLD?";

$strWords          = explode(' ', $str);
$strLettersRowsArr = array_map('str_split', $strWords);

$maxRows = 0;
foreach ($strLettersRowsArr as $lettersArr) {
    if (count($lettersArr) > $maxRows) {
        $maxRows = count($lettersArr);
    }
}

foreach ($strLettersRowsArr as $key => &$lettersArr) {
    while (count($lettersArr) < $maxRows) {
        $lettersArr[] = ' ';
    }
}
unset($lettersArr);

$strLettersColumnsArr = [];
for ($row = 0; $row < $maxRows; $row++) {
    $strLettersColumnsArr[] = array_column($strLettersRowsArr, $row);
}

// Print out letter columns.
foreach ($strLettersColumnsArr as $lettersColumnArr) {
    foreach ($lettersColumnArr as $letter) {
        echo "$letter ";
    }
    echo "\n";
}
?>
```

But I get this output:

```
??
??
??
??
??
```

Comment: In latin characters works. But when i set greek letter  the output is question marks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Greek letters - multibyte. This is the cause of the problem.

You can solve it:

Replace this:

`$strLettersRowsArr = array_map('str_split', $strWords);`

by:

`$strLettersRowsArr = array_map(function($word) {
    return preg_split('##u', $word, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
}, $strWords);`

Comment: Unfortunately it works in php 5.5. In php 5.2 dont work and thus dont recognize the array_column function

Comment: Of course, this function was not in 5.2. You can write it yourself, it's simple. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php